# Angular2 Event: keyup exits input

Tags: javascript, events, angular, angular2-template

I have an input element bound to a property of my component which should update as of when I change the text in the input field.

My code so far:

```
<input type="text" #updatetext [value]="item.name" (keyup)="updateItem(item.$key, updatetext.value)" />
```

The problem is that when I make a keystroke, the element looses focus, means I have to click on it again to continue typing.

How can I solve this? Am I going with the wrong approach?

**UPDATE**

`updateItem` simply modifies the array. (I'm using it with firebase/angularfire2 btw.)

```
updateItem(key: string, newText: string) {
    this.items.update(key, { name: newText });
}
```

So the data itself is: `items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;` and consists of only the key and name properties (both are strings).

**Update 2**
It's not because the whole dom element is recreated, or at least shouldn't according to [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html#!%23change-propagation) (see "change propagation").

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are creating the input with `*ngFor`.

If `updateItem()` modifies the array that `*ngFor` iterates over, then the element might be recreated, which is why your element loses focus (it's now a different element).

Simple version (depending on what's going on exactly with your data, this might not work)

```
items.subscribe(response => {
  for(item in response) {
    var found = this.itemsCopy.find((copy) => copy.name == item.name); 
    if(found.length) {
      found[0].value = item.value
    }
  }
})
```

Then use `itemsCopy` in `*ngFor`.

Comment: Yup that's right, I'm using *ngFor. Seems logical.
Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is `updateItem` doing. How does the data look like `*ngFor` is iterating over.

Comment: Updated the question, is this clear enough? Thanks for helping. :)

Comment: I don't see an easy solution except maintaining a copy of the array and updating its values from the `FirebaseListObservable` and passing the copy to `*ngFor`.

Comment: How would you do this in code? Can you update your answer?

Comment: I updated my answer but it depends on what exactly is going on with your data (value modifications, adds, removes, ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122100/discussion-between-sandrooco-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to dive deeper into this problem. I don't have the time.